# Как в javascript при наведении на div отобразить скрытый блок

Tags: javascript

а если убрать мышь в сторону, то блок не должен исчезать.

Comment: Ваши попытки кода можно увидеть? или вам хочется чтобы вам дали готовый код?

Comment: При наведении на какой див,какой блок показывать?))

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
$('#one').hover(function(){
$('#two').toggle()
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">наводим сюда</div>
<div id="two">lorem ipsum a.................................................</div>
```